# Differentiating using Calculator Trick with Definite Derivative

Tags: calculus, calculator

Differentiate $y=sec^2(x)$

Answer in Problem Set: $2x\cdot sec^2(x)\cdot tan^2(x)$

Answer in Wolfram Alpha: $2 \cdot tan(x) \cdot sec^2(x)$

We can always solve it manually, deriving and stuff; but board exam has very limited time therefore we were told its always better to use shortcut. My Calculator, a Casio FX-991ES Plus can only evaluate Definite Derivatives but not give me the answer straightforward.

So I try:

```
d/dx ((2*x)*(sec^2(x))*(tan^2(x)))
```

with $x = 2.5$ radians and I get a the derivative of

```
-2.327784695
```

Then when I use the correct answer from the problem set

```
(2*x)*(sec^2(x))*(tan^2(x))
```

and plug in $x = 2.5$, I get a different answer:

```
4.347267676...
```

How can that be? Isn't that supposed to be the slope? How can I avoid this problem?

Comment: This is what you get from WA's answer evaluated at $x = 2.5$ though; I wouldn't trust the answer in the problem set.

Comment: Don't know about you, but it would take me about $3$ seconds to find the derivative "manually", and probably about $30$ seconds to do all that evaluation stuff.  Why not just learn to differentiate instead of playing the "exam game"?  BTW the given answer is wrong.

Comment: @David because there are 500 multiple choice items; in 5 hours. Twice  for two days. encompassing the entirety of mechanical engineering; from algebra to power plants. while its nice to see how wonderful and ingenious one's solution is; there is not enough time or space in the head to cram all formulas. thats not to say i don't know how to derive manually. i do. i just can't spend too much time on one.

Comment: The point remains that in this case I would have been $10$ times slower doing it your way.  Maybe it's different for you.  Anyway, it's your exam not mine so never mind.

Comment: Rather than the phrase "definite derivative" I think you mean "numeric derivative."

Comment: Are we sure we aren't talking about $\sec(x^2)$? That has derivative $2x\sec(x^2)\tan(x^2)$ which is the answer in the problem set, if you just misinterpret or typo the ^2.